# Show the video when the image is clicked using handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I am trying to work on a webpage in which when I click on the image tag I should be able to show the hidden video. I used handlebars. I also want to close this video when some user clicks on some other photo.

```
    <script type = "text/x-handlebars-template" id = "template">
            <div class = "row row-eq-height">
                {{#each images}}
                    <div class = " col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                        <div class = "thumbnail">
                            <img src = "{{src}}" style = "width : 50%;height :25%;" 
                             onClick = document.getElementById("video").style.display = "block";/>
                            <iframe style = "display:none;" id = "video" src = "{{video}}"/>
                            <h3>{{Song}}</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
    </script>
```

This is not working the videos are hidden but they fail to display back when I press on a photo.
[image: This is how it looks. I want my video to play when I click on an image.They should disappear when I click on other and that other video has to start playing.]
Please do feel free to ask questions incase you need more clarity what my query is.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need an script or other for the onclick. Can't do it solely using handlebars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve a better performance, I suggest you just create everything but iframe. When someone click video thumbnail, create iframe in the fly and append to parent. If you do so, you won't have to hide videos and trying to display them.

```
<div class="video-container" data-video="{{video}}">
  <div class="video-overlay" onclick="fetchVideo()">
    <img src = "{{src}}" class="video-thumbnail"/>
    <h3>{{Song}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="video-player"></div>
</div>
```

```
.video-player {
 // this is iframe container
}
.video-overlay {
  // syles
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}
.video-thumbnail {
  width : 50%;
  height: 25%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```
function fetchVideo() {
  let parent = event.target.parentElement;
  let video = parent.dataset.video;
  let iframe = `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="${video}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>`;
  let player = event.target.nextElementSibling;
  player.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', iframe);
  event.target.classList.add("hidden");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am new to javascript and I am confused I want the video to appear when I click on the image but in your code, the onClick function is written in "video-overlay".May I know how it contributes to my task

Comment: video-overlay is the container of image and song name. My mistake, I should have added them. I edited my answer.

Comment: The video is not playing. The video plays fine when I give video id instead of ${video} in function fetchVideo(). Am I supposed to give any class with id = "video"? Please help

Comment: I just noticed that you stored the whole URL, not just the video id in the video variable. Making iframe's src=`${video}` should work. I updated my answer.

Comment: Look at this : https://codepen.io/bulentAkgul/pen/pobJgVE?editors=1111 But I suggest you store only video ID. So you can use it maybe some other way later on. For instance, you can put a video link instead of embedding it.